# I want to write a function to manipulate a spark-dataframe column value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Code to create dataframe:

```py
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Jose", "BLUE"),
        ("lI", "BrOwN")
    ],
    ["name", "eye_color"]
)
```

I have written following code to convert the 'eye-color' column to lowercase:

```py
actual_df = source_df
for col_name in actual_df.columns if column == 'eye_color' else column for column in actual_df.columns:
    actual_df = actual_df.withColumn(col_name, lower(col(col_name)))
```

I am getting following error:

```
Cell In [26], line 2
  for col_name in actual_df.columns if column == 'eye_color' else column for column in actual_df.columns:
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your list comprehension or for loop there. Seems like you want a loop but are using comprehension syntax.

Comment: If all you need is to transfor the `eye_color` column, why not just `actual_df.withColumn('eye_color_lower', lower(actual_df.eye_color)).drop('eye_color').withColumnRenamed('eye_color_lower', 'eye_color')` or something similar (such as select expr, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a python problem than a spark problem. Your python syntax is not correct.

If you want to keep the same structure, that is make a transformation for each column that matches some criteria, there are multiple ways to do it:

```py
# using a if
for col_name in actual_df.columns:
    if col_name == 'eye_color':
        actual_df = actual_df.withColumn(col_name, lower(col(col_name)))

# using filter
for col_name in filter(lambda column: column == 'eye_color', actual_df.columns):
    actual_df = actual_df.withColumn(col_name, lower(col(col_name)))

# using list comprehension
for col_name in [column for column in actual_df.columns if column == 'eye_color']:
    actual_df = actual_df.withColumn(col_name, lower(col(col_name)))
```

But in your situation, as mentioned in one comment, since you only transform one column I would not use a loop. A single `withColumn` would do the trick.

```py
source_df.withColumn('eye_color', lower(col('eye_color')))
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning different ways to do it , this helped me